# how to reduce time taken

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity, compile-time

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void rotateByOne(int arr[], int n)
{
    int x = arr[0];
    for (int y = 0; y < n - 1; y++)
    {
        arr[y] = arr[y + 1];
    }
    arr[n - 1] = x;
}

int main()
{
    int n, d;

    cin >> n >> d;

    int arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    while (d != 0)
    {
        rotateByOne(arr, n);
        d--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

How Do i Reduce the compile time of this code which is written to take an array input of n integers and rotate array left by d times.......
I found this on hacker rank and geeksforgeeks, Iam getting correct output from this code but the problem is time.

Comment: Do you mean "run-time" instead of "compile-time" ?

Comment: `cin>>n>>d;  int arr[n];` -- *I found this on hacker rank and geeksforgeeks* -- Sigh, another new programmer thinking this is valid C++ from these sites.  Use `std::vector<int> arr(n);` instead.

Comment: Don't rotate by 1 `d` times. Rotate by `d` once.

Comment: Note that rotating an array of size N N times ends up with the original array.

Comment: I just compiled and ran the code and it did both of these instantly. What compiler are you using?

Comment: btw, this code practice is really bad, if you are a new programmer please don't take example from code like this.

Comment: It would be easier to create a new (rotated) array that to rotate in-place. Moreover, if the goal is simply to write the rotated array, you don't need to modify the array or to create another one.

Comment: [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).  And you should rotate left `N mod d` times, not `d` times.  What if the array had two elements, and you are to rotate left a billion times?  Are you going to write a loop that goes up to a billion?

Comment: `int arr[n];` is not valid standard C++ as `n` is not a constexpr expression.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually its given in question that  1<= d <= n

Comment: *Actually its given in question that 1<= d <= n* -- But that constraint was *not* presented here in your question.  The title of your thread even states "how to reduce time taken", indicating there may be inefficiencies in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is simply to write the rotated array, you don't need to modify the array or to create another one.

Note: using two loops instead of one allows to avoid the use of the modulo operation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = arr.size();
    int d = 3;

    for (int i = d; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use ready [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and read [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate_copy).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);

    int n, d;
    std::cin >> n >> d;

    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, n, std::back_inserter(v));

    std::rotate_copy(v.begin(), v.begin() + d, v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/mGciaeJqiH5PjGm1