# Rotation of an array with specific number of rotation

Tags: c++, arrays, rotation

So I am trying to perform the rotation operation given number of times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void result_arr_one_rotation (int arr [], int n){
  // int one_rotate_arr[n];
  int p=arr[0];
   for (int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
  }
  arr[n]=p;
  //return arr;
}


int main(){
//n stands for total number of elements in array and d stands for number of rotation
  int n,d;
  cin>>n>>d;
  int arr[n];
  //to take elements of array
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
  }
  //int rotated_arr[n];
  for (int i=0;i<d;i++){
      result_arr_one_rotation(arr,n);
      //cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  }
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now, the function `result_arr_one_rotation` rotate elements by one index.To store 0th index element I have created `p` variable which is assigned at last. You can see that by 'arr[n]=p' line. Now, I have rotated at `d` times as user has freedom to use how many times it rotates. 
AND then I simply print out the elements.

**Now here is the problem when I have given inputs like**

```
5 which is number of elements(n)
2 number of rotation d
1 2 3 4 5 -> answer it should be
3 4 5 5 5-> this is the answer comes out
```

Please anyone tell me what did I do wrong here?

Comment: `int arr[n];` is not standard C++ and you probably should be using `std::rotate`

Comment: "1 2 3 4 5 -> answer it should be" Why? For what input?

Comment: About the same question was asked today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340097/how-to-reduce-time-taken , but with a useless title

Comment: Yunnosch Hence this is circular rotation we want to shift 2 elements to the left and first 2 elements will be put onto last 2 index. As there is no more space left on the left indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last index you use in this loop

```
for (int i=0;i<n-1;++i){
    arr[i]=arr[i+1];
}
```

is `n-2`. Valid indicees in arrays are 0 till size-1. Here

```
arr[n]=p;
```

you access the array out-of-bounds. If you want to assign to the last element, that would be `arr[n-1] = p;`

If you do not want to use [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) because this is an exercise, I would still urge you to use `std::vector`, because you are using a variable length array which is not standard C++. Actually there is not really a need for VLAs in C++, because it has `std::vector`. They are more of a C thing and gcc offers them as non-standard extension also in C++.